# how to add wcf reference in Monodevelp

Tags: wcf, monodevelop

New to Monodevelop
How do i add reference to wcf in Monodevelop. I do not see any option to add wcf reference the version i am using is 2.8.6.5 and running on windows 7

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Add Web Reference command now supports adding references based on WCF. When adding the reference, and combo box allows selecting the target framework, which can be WCF.  Right-click on the project in the solution explorer and go to Add Web Reference.